# Axios post request error Cannot create property 'url' on string

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I ma trying to do a post request and I am encountring this issue when I try to submit my request.

`Cannot create property 'url' on string`

What I am not understanding is that the last few fields that I am sending in the POST are strings which the first four fields are, but it only pulls the issue with the first four fields.

This are the 4 fields:

```
        subject,
        leaderAlias,
        excludeLeaderOrg,
        excludeUserAlias,
```

CODE:

```js
const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
const [leaderAlias, setLeaderAlias] = useState("");
const [excludeLeaderOrg, setExcludeLeaderOrg] = useState("");
const [excludeUserAlias, setExcludeUserAlias] = useState("");
const [timeNA, setTimeNA] = useState("");
const [dateNA, setDateNA] = useState("");

const [timeEU, setTimeEU] = useState("");
const [dateEU, setDateEU] = useState("");

const [timeIN, setTimeIN] = useState("");
const [dateIN, setDateIN] = useState("");

const [exclusionDays, setExclusionDays] = useState("");
const [retries, setRetries] = useState("");
const [esclation, setEsclation] = useState(false);
const [emailBody, setEmailBody] = useState("");
      sendPagerAuditEmail(

        subject,
        leaderAlias,
        excludeLeaderOrg,
        excludeUserAlias,

        [
          {"NA" : {"Date": dateNA, "Time": timeNA, "Timezone:": "PST"} }, 
          {"EU" : {"Time": dateEU, "Date": timeEU, "Timezone:": "GMT"} },
          {"IN" : {"Time": dateIN, "Date": timeIN, "Timezone:": "IST"} }
        ],
        exclusionDays,
        retries,
        esclation,
        emailBody
      );
```

Request Code:

```
export const sendPagerAuditEmail = (
  subject,
  leaderAlias,
  excludeLeaderOrg,
  excludeUserAlias,
  region_datetime,
  exclusionDays,
  retries,
  esclation,
  emailBody
) => {
  frameURL =
    APIURL +
    "UpdatePagerAudit?email_subject=" +
    subject +
    "&leader_alias=" +
    leaderAlias +
    "&exclude_leader_org=" +
    excludeLeaderOrg +
    "&exclude_leader_alias=" +
    excludeUserAlias +
    "&region_datetime=" +
    region_datetime +
    "&exclusion_days=" +
    exclusionDays +
    "&retries=" +
    retries +
    "&esclation=" +
    esclation +
    "&email_body=" +
    emailBody;
  return connectAPI("POST", frameURL, { subject: subject, leaderAlias: leaderAlias, excludeLeaderOrg: excludeLeaderOrg, excludeUserAlias: excludeUserAlias,  region_datetime: region_datetime, exclusionDays: exclusionDays ,retries: retries ,emailBody: emailBody});
};
```

Connect API code:

```
const connectAPI = (requestType, url, body) => {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  return axios({
    method: requestType,
    url: url,
    data: body,
  });
};
```

Everything seems to be set up correctly, not sure if I need to convert to JSON somewhere. There are other request similar to the one I have set up and they are working correctly.